# calling function inside preg_replace thats inside a function

Tags: php, function, preg-replace, syntax-error

I have some code with the a structure similar to this

```
           function bbcode($Text)
           { //$Text = preg_replace("/\[video\](.+?)\[\/video\]/",embed_video($1), $Text);
    return $Text;}

    function embed_video($url){
if (preg_match("/http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch\?v=([0-9a-zA-Z-_]*)(.*)/i", $url, $matches)) {
    return '<object width="425" height="350">'.
           '<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/'.$matches[1].'" />'.
           '<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />'.
           '<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/'.$matches[1].'&autoplay="0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" width="425" height="350" />'.
           '</object>';
}
    return $url;
    }

$lolcakes = "[video]http://youtube.com/id/xxxxxxpron[/video]";
$lolcakesconverted = bbcode($lolcakes);
```

The problem is it spits an error back at me.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_VARIABLE or '$'

Have any ideas on how i can call embed_video inside of the preg_replace of the bbcode function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the "e" modifier on `preg_replace()` (see [Pattern Modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php))

```
return preg_replace("/\[video\](.+?)\[\/video\]/e", "embed_video('$1')", $Text);
```

which tells `preg_replace()` to treat the second parameter as PHP code.

Comment: Actually, the "/e" modifier is deprecated (as can lead to a security vulnerability) and you should use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) instead

Answer (score 41):

try [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback)

```
return preg_replace_callback("/\[video\](.+?)\[\/video\]/", 'embed_video', $Text);

function embed_video($matches)
{
  return $matches[1] . 'foo';      
}
```

Comment: maybe i should have been a bit more specific

the embed_video() has another preg_replace inside it

Comment: that's fine, you can do any transformations necessary in embed_video... preg_replace_callback will call it for any matches found and take the result

Comment: If the callback is a class method instead of an independent function, we can use `$callback = [ $this, 'method_name' ];`.

Comment: The /e modifier is no longer supported, use preg_replace_callback