# php: replace text within a container with link. preg_replace?

Tags: php, preg-replace, replace, str-replace

I've searched for an answer to what seems like a simple question, but to no avail.

I have some HTML output, eg:

```
<div id="attachment_1098" class="wp-caption alignleft" style="width: 160px">[[ a href="mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/photo-1.jpg" ]][[img class="size-thumbnail wp-image-1098" title="John Doe" src="mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/photo-1.jpg" alt="John Doe" width="150" height="200" /]][[ /a ]]<p class="wp-caption-text">John Doe</p></div>
<div id="attachment_1080" class="wp-caption alignleft" style="width: 160px">[[ a href="mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/photo-2.jpg" ]][[img class="size-thumbnail wp-image-1080" title="Fred Bloggs" src="mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/photo-1.jpg" alt="Fred Bloggs" width="150" height="200" /]][[ /a ]]<p class="wp-caption-text">Fred Bloggs</p></div>
<div id="attachment_1099" class="wp-caption alignleft" style="width: 160px">[[ a href="mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/photo-3.jpg" ]][[img class="size-thumbnail wp-image-1099" title="Jane Doe" src="mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/photo-3.jpg" alt="Jane Doe" width="150" height="200" /]][[ /a ]]<p class="wp-caption-text">Jane Doe</p></div>
<div id="attachment_1096" class="wp-caption alignleft" style="width: 160px">[[ a href="mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/photo-4.jpg" ]][[img class="size-thumbnail wp-image-1096" title="Joe Public" src="mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/photo-4.jpg" alt="Joe Public" width="150" height="200" /]][[ /a ]]<p class="wp-caption-text">Joe Public</p></div>
```

*(The above html is actually well formed, had to replace < & > in anchours and images with [[ and ]] respectively so it would post.)*

I'd like to wrap a link around the text content of each (p) with a class of "wp-caption-text", the url of which should have the following format:

```
'/my-page-root/'.strtolower(str_replace(' ','-',$linkText)).'';
```

(so John Doe would link to: */my-page-root/john-doe* etc)

Now, I've got so far with preg_replace, but I can't figure out how to create the link URL from the backreference. This makes me think there must be an easier way to do it (and possibly a quicker way?)

Anyway, here's the code I got up to:

```
<?php $contentLinked = preg_replace("/(<p class=\"wp-caption-text\">.*<\/p>)/Us", "<p class=\"wp-caption-text\"><a href=\"\">$1</a></p>",$content); ?>
```

That replaces the text with an empty anchour just fine, I'm stuck with how to use the backreference to create the link url.

**A few Notes**:

The link must only wrap the text (may need to only wrap part of the text later on, but I'll cross that bridge when I come to it)

Wordpress won't allow this through the wysiwyg without a workaround to prevent stripping the links, one day someone else might come in and wreck the format (hence the hard coding) so there are no useful wp workarounds for this.

The link on the image must remain to the full sized image (jquery gallery going on), so wrapping the entire image and/or div in the link is not an option

Cheers for any help you can give me.

**Andy**

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put the part that you want to match (the text) in parentheses in order for it to be saved in a backreference. Like this:

```
<?php $contentLinked = preg_replace("/(<p class=\"wp-caption-text\">(.*)<\/p>)/Us", "<p class=\"wp-caption-text\"><a href=\"\">$1</a></p>",$content); ?>
```

Comment: ah yes, of course, good catch Jordi. Any idea how I can use the now correct backreference to form a url? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I've done it!

Thanks to Jordi for spotting the original flaw.

I found this [calling function inside preg_replace thats inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082207/calling-function-inside-preg-replace-thats-inside-a-function)

which lead me towards using preg_replace_callback() instead (never used it before, never had the cause)

In case anyone else has a similar problem, my resulting code goes like so:

```
<?php $contentLinked = preg_replace_callback("/<p class=\"wp-caption-text\">(.*)<\/p>/Us", 'myCallback',$content);?>
```

and the function:

```
<?php 
function myCallback($match){

        return '<a href="'.strtolower(str_replace(' ','-',$match[1])).'">'.$match[1].'</a>';

    }
?>
```