# replace special strings in a html page by php

Tags: php, html

I am looking for a way to replace all string looking alike in entire page with their defined values

Please do not recommend me other methods of including language constants.

Strings like this :

[_HOME]

[_NEWS]

all of them are looking the same in [_*] part

Now the big issue is how to scan a HTML page and to replace the defined values .

One ways to parse the html page is to use DOMDocument and then pre_replace() it

**but my main problem is writing a pattern for the replacement**

```
$pattern = "/[_i]/";
$replacement= custom_lang("/i/");
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$htmlPage = $doc->loadHTML($html);

preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $htmlPage);
```

Comment: In this case, you don't need DOMDocument - just to a `str_replace()` if you know what you're looking for.

Comment: It's not that easy, check the replacement part of my question . I should check each string in language file for its defined value

Comment: How could you possibly know what to replace an unknown key with?

Comment: In that case, try [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RegEx, `[]` are operators, so if you use them you need to escape them.

Other problem with your expression is `_*` which will match Zero or more `_`. You need to replace it with some meaningful match, Like, `_.*` which will match _ and any other characters after that. SO your full expression becomes,

`/\[_.*?\]/`

Hey, why an `?`, you might be tempted to ask: The reason being that it performs a non-greedy match. Like,

`[_foo] [_bar]` is the query string then a greedy match shall return one match and give you the whole of it because your expression is fully valid for the string but a non-greedy match will get you two seperate matches.  ([More information](http://www.itworld.com/nl/perl/01112001))

You might be better-off in being more constrictive, by having an `_` followed by Capital letters. Like,

`/\[_[A-Z]+\]/`

**Update**: Using the matched strings and replacing them. To do so we use the concept called back-refrencing.

Consider modifying the above expression, enclosing the string in parentheses, like, `/\[_([A-Z]+)\]/`

Now in `preg-replace` arguments we can use the expression in parentheses by back-referencing them with `$1`. So what you can use is,

```
preg_replce("/\[_([A-Z]+)\]/e", "my_wonderful_replacer('$1')", $html);
```

**Note**: We needed the `e modifier` to treat the second parameter as PHP code. ([More information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082207/calling-function-inside-preg-replace-thats-inside-a-function))

Comment: Nice pattern , and may I ask , how to preg_replace these strings in my output page, and check my question $replacement= custom_lang("/i/");  , by i ,  I mean the item that needs to be replaced.

Answer (score -1):

If you know the full keyword you are trying to replace (e.g. `[_HOME]`), then you can just use [str_replace()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace all instances.

No need to make things like this more complex by introducing regex.

Comment: It is not only [_HOME] , what if my client uses [_SOMETHING_I_DONT_KNOW] , its complex in itself, and that's why I had the question, I need to find the pattern and reg_replace all strings like this