# preg_replace use reference as variable key

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to allow for formatting tags in my script which will allow users to type in their content things such as `%fullname%`, `%telephone%`, `%phoneno%` etc, and it will replace the text between the two `%` with a variable that has a name matching the captured group.

So far I have tried something similar to this:

```
<?php
$user['fullname'=>'John','age'=>24,'telephone'=>'0123456789'];
$content = 'Hello %fullname% you are %age% years old and your tel no is %telephone%';
$content = preg_replace('/%(fullname|telephone|age)%/', $user[{$1}], $content);
var_dump($content);
```

But it fails to work. Not sure how to achieve what I want, or if it's even possible in the way I'm trying?

Any help is appreciated in advance.
Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2082209/3832970

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Nice find ^ ^.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this worked perfectly! Thank you for the find. I wasn't sure exactly the correct 'name' of what I was trying to do, so it made it harder to find a solution! Thanks!